# How correctly retrieve an image into the res/drawable/ folder of an Android project?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-resources

I am absolutly new in Android development and I have the following problem.

I have an image named **colosseum_icon.png** into the **drawable** diretory of the **res** folder and I have to retrieve it into my Java code. So I tryed to use the **R** class in this way:

```
Image image = R.drawable.colosseum_icon;
```

but it give me an error because it seems that in this way return an int value (maybe the identifier of this resource? or what?)

What am I missing? How can I retriev the previous image into my Java code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When and why should one use getResources()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788390/when-and-why-should-one-use-getresources)

Comment: "I have an image named colosseum_icon.png into the drawable diretory of the res folder" -- please bear in mind that `res/drawable/` is a legacy synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`. It is unlikely that you really want to put this icon in `res/drawable/`. "I have to retrieve it into my Java code" -- what exactly do you intend to do with it? An `Image` class does not really have much of anything to do with a drawable resource. "maybe the identifier of this resource?" -- correct.

Comment: Tip: If you are loading large images and want to avoid a potential future out of memory error, consider using an image loading library like [Picasso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158425/picasso-load-drawable-resources-from-their-uri)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.colosseum_icon);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need a `Context`  (i.e. an `Activity` or `Service`) to retrive resourse like images embedded in your app.

If your are trying to get an `Image` (Abstract class) or `Bitmap` object  from an activity class:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.colosseum_icon);
```

If your a new to Android dev please take look at this about Context:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18327529/4562521

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) Find your `ImageView` field:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_image_field_id);
```

2) Set your **png icon** to that field:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_icon_name);
```

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android)

You can get it as a bitmap by using.

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                               R.drawable.colosseum_icon);
```